# Dude, looks kinda sticky

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I'm looking for a two-word phrase (twelve letters).**

---

### B: P(□)

### Y: P(○)

### B+Y=?

---

### |L|UL|U|UR|R|D|

### |DR|DR|DL|DL|

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is

> VITRUVIAN MAN

Reasoning

> If we take **B** to indicate "blue" and **Y** to indicate "yellow", then the first set of instructions is telling us to draw a square through the blue dots and a circle through the yellow dots, where we count "green" dots as being both blue and yellow (B+Y=?).
>  The second set of instructions tell us how to connect, respectively, the upper and lower central black dots to the rest of the image, e.g, UL in the first row indicates a line joining the upper black dot to the dot to its *upper left*.
>  If we do all that we get the following image
>  [image]
>  which looks like a stick figure version of da Vinci's *Vitruvian Man*
>  [image]

Comment: All good, great job!